Condition for integral convergence in n-dimensional space.
We know the condition that $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ must meet in order for $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}dx$ to converge. But what about the integral of $\int_{B\left( 0,1 \right)}^{}\frac{1}{\left\| x \right\|^{\alpha}}$? Where $B\left( 0,1 \right)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$.  What conditions should $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ meet for that integral to converge? The cases of $n=2,3$ are easy because we can use the techniques of integration we know from vector calculus, but i don't know how to do it for $n>4$. 
Any ideas?

Have you looked https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball ?

I think integrating in spherical coordinates could be the way to go, but what'd be the jacobian in that case?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere

Prove first that the volume of $B(0,r)$ is of the form $c_nr^n$ (you don't need to integrate! It's a proof by scaling!) for some $c_n>0$ that depends only on the dimension and use that to prove that if $\alpha\geq n$ then the integral diverges (consider the integral over $B(0,r)$ and make $r$ go to $0$) the other direction is trickier. Try to bound it above by a sum and show that said sum converges

It's easy to see by an argument of scaling that the volume of $B(0,r)$ in $n$ dimensions is of the form $c_nr^n$ where $c_n=Vol(B(0,1))>0$ is a constant that only depends on the dimension. The actual constant can be calculated but we won't actually care about it. Now, let $B_k=B(0,1/k)\backslash B(0,1/(k+1))$ and $\chi(B_k)$ be the indicator function of $B_k$, we have, by Tonelli
\begin{align}\int_{B(0,1)}\frac1{||x||^\alpha}\;dV&=\int_{B(0,1)}\left(\sum_{k\geq1}\chi(B_k)\right)\frac1{||x||^\alpha}\;dV\\\\&=\sum_{k\geq1}\int_{B(0,1)}\chi(B_k)\frac1{||x||^\alpha}\;dV\\\\&=\sum_{k\geq1}\int_{B_k}\frac1{||x||^\alpha}\;dV\end{align}
now, notice that in $B_k$ we have $\frac1{k+1}\leq ||x||\leq\frac1k$ therefore, we have on one hand
\begin{align}\sum_{k\geq1}\int_{B_k}\frac1{||x||^\alpha}\;dV&\leq \sum_{k\geq1}(k+1)^{\alpha}Vol(B_k)\\\\&\leq\sum_{k\geq1}(k+1)^{\alpha}\left(c_n\frac1{k^n}-c_n\frac1{(k+1)^n}\right)\\\\&\leq c_n\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(k+1)^\alpha((k+1)^n-k^n)}{k^n(k+1)^n}\\\\&\leq nc_n\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1+o_k(1)}{k^{n-\alpha+1}}\end{align}
which converges for $\alpha<n$. On the other hand
\begin{align}\sum_{k\geq1}\int_{B_k}\frac1{||x||^\alpha}\;dV&\geq \sum_{k\geq1}k^{\alpha}Vol(B_k)\\\\&\geq\sum_{k\geq1}k^{\alpha}\left(c_n\frac1{k^n}-c_n\frac1{(k+1)^n}\right)\\\\&\leq c_n\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k^\alpha((k+1)^n-k^n)}{k^n(k+1)^n}\\\\&\geq nc_n\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1+o_k(1)}{k^{n-\alpha+1}}\end{align}
which diverges if $\alpha\geq n$. Therefore, the integral converges if and only if $\alpha< n$

If the scaling argument didn't convince you, here's a proof via integration. By a change of variables we have
$$Vol(B(0,r))=\int_{B(0,r)}dV=\int_{B(0,1)}\frac{dV}{|\det(r^{-1}I)|}=r^n\int_{B(0,1)}dV=Vol(B(0,1))r^n=c_nr^n$$
